# Spawn New Process and Return to Expect Script

Tags: bash, shell, expect, spawn

I am using an Expect script to automate the installation of a program. Because of an issue with one of the install dependencies, I need to pause the installation process at a specific point to edit the `db.properties` file. Once that file is changed, I can resume the installation process. I can spawn a new process in the middle of the installation to do this, but I get the "spawn id exp5 not open" error after closing that process.

`db_edit.sh` edits the appropriate file:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
filename=db.properties
sed -i "s/<some_regex>/<new_db_info>/g" $filename
```

My automated installation script spawns the above script in the middle of its execution:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Run the installer and log the output
spawn ./install.bin
log_file install_output.log

# Answer installer questions
# for simplicity, let's pretend there is only one
expect "PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE:"
send "\r"

# Now I need to pause the installation and edit that file
spawn ./db_edit.sh
set db_edit_ID $spawn_id
close -i $db_edit_ID
send_log "DONE"

# Database Connection - the following must happen AFTER the db_edit script runs
expect "Hostname (Default: ):"
send "my_host.com\r"
# more connection info ...

expect eof
```

The output log `install_output.log` shows the following error:

```
PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE: spawn ./db_edit.sh^M
DONEexpect: spawn id exp5 not open
    while executing
"expect "Hostname (Default: ):""^M
```

The database info has been modified correctly, so I know the script works and it is indeed spawned. However, when I close that process, the spawn id of the installation process is also apparently closed, which causes the `spawn id exp5 not open` error.

Also curious is that the spawn appears to happen before it should. The response to `"PRESS <ENTER>"` should be `"\r"` or `^M` to indicate that `ENTER` was sent.

How can I fix this to resume the installation script after closing `db_edit.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to automate any interactivity with that script, so don't use `spawn`

```
exec db_edit.sh
```

This way, you're not interfering with the spawn_id of the currently spawned process.